# Chrome Browser not opening in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, selenium-chromedriver

My chrome browser not opening in Selenium Webdriver .I have downloaded all things like chrome driver , selenium jars and chrome according to compatibility. I am using Intellij IDEA IDE.The code and version details are given below -

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\driver\chromedriver_win32.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

**Versions:**
Chrome:89.0.4389.90
IDE:IntelliJ IDEA : 203.7148.57
Chrome driver: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=89.0.4389.23/
Selenium Webdriver: selenium-java-4.0.0-beta-2
(I have tried with selenium old version as well)

Please give some suggestions .
Thanks .

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable must exist: C:\driver\chromedriver_win32.exe

Comment: does that driver exists in that path ?

Comment: Try adding double back slashes: `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\driver\\chromedriver_win32.exe")`

Comment: @PDHide Yes driver exists in the same path .

Comment: With double back slash also , same error is coming.

Answer (score -1):

Remove **_win32** and than try
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\driver\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();